# Can a windows backup be restored in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I overwrote my windows partition when I installed ubuntu by not selecting the correct choice during install. Looking at various forums, it seems that I cannot restore back to windows once ubuntu is installed (even with 3rd part tool). I believe my only option is a recovery CD (windows) in order to get the windows backup in a recognizable format. for restoration. Am
 I correct in my thinking?

Comment: How exactly did you back up though?

Comment: I backed up windows prior to installing ubuntu via windows backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If during the Ubuntu installation you chose to use the entire disk, then yes you would have lost your Windows partition.

If you want to dual-boot your system with Windows and Ubuntu, you have to first:

- Live boot using Ubuntu
- Wipe your whole harddrive using Gparted
- Create two partitions: one for Windows and one for Ubuntu(No
  filesystem type needed)

Now reboot you system with the Windows boot media and install it to one of the partitions. Leave the other partition as free space.

When Windows is done installing, reboot using the Ubuntu cd and install this system on to the secondary partition.

It's very important that you install Windows **before** Linux if you want to use Grub as your boot selector.

Comment: Thanks Kris. That is what I was trying to do.  Where I went wrong was when it was time to install  ubuntu, it chose the windows partition instead of the free space partition I created. I thought it odd it did not ask me what partition I wanted to install on. I think I will do the dual boot option next time to be safe.  Either way, I have to get a hold of a windows CD, and see if I can salvage the data I lost. Thanks for you confirmation.

Comment: No problem :). Please upvote my answer if you found it usefull. Goodluck with your data recovery!